# Why is the answer order randomized?

Tags: support, answers

I think the new system of randomizing the answers regardless of Votes is Flawed.

It appears that users are (most likely unintentionally) abusing this. Simply re-word the current best answer and you have 50% being up voted (or even accepted) over the original because you are listed first.

I think it would be better to order them based on Time answered.

PS: I do understand the intent was to correct the bias towards the answer with the most votes. But I think this unintended side effect is worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What new system?

There is randomisation of answers (which isn't new) but it only occurs between answers that have the same vote score and when you have the "votes" tab active. The other two tabs - "oldest" and "active" are consistent in their answer ordering.

"oldest" lists the answers in order of age of initial posting.

"active" lists the answers in reverse order of edits - the most recently edited posts appearing first.

Comment: I never notices those links! Did the default selection change? (I must have click "active"on in err)

Comment: @Morons - I don't think the defaults have changed in a while. I think it's votes, but I always sort by activity.